# cb=gapi.loaded_0:76 Uncaught uO {message: "Invalid cookiePolicy"

Tags: javascript

I am developing Chrome extension to write data to spreadsheet. This is my first extension. But while sending request to spreadsheet it is giving some strange error.

error: cb=gapi.loaded_0:76 Uncaught uO {message: "Invalid cookiePolicy", stack: "gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookieP…is.google.com/js/client.js?_=1537034052136:3:672)"}

I am trying to authenticate user and probably, its going wrong somewhere. Can anyone please help?

background.js

```
var CLIENT_ID = "1052562111231-8v0luivnri8vuh6bsmo6v5ocls4apv4m.apps.googleusercontent.com";

var SCOPES = [
  'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
  'https://docs.google.com/feeds'
];  
var discoveryUrl = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4'; 
var x;

xhrWithAuth();


function xhrWithAuth() {
    console.log("xhrWithAuth");
    var access_token;
    var retry = true;
    getToken();

    function getToken() {
        chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
            'interactive': true
        }, function(token) {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError || !token) {
                console.log('getAuthToken', chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                // callback(chrome.runtime.lastError);
                return;
            }
            console.log(token);
        $.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/client.js", function () {

        gapi.load('client', function () {

        console.log("gapi.client is loaded")
        gapi.auth.setToken({
        'access_token': token
       });

        gapi.auth.authorize({
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
        'immediate': true
    }, handleAuthResult(token));
            });
        });

        });
    }


}


function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    console.log(authResult)
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        loadSheetsApi();
    } else {
           console.log("no authentication");
  }

}

function loadSheetsApi() {
    console.log('loadSheetsApi'); 
    var requests = ["abc","def"];
    console.log(requests); 
    var discoveryUrl = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4';
    gapi.client.load(discoveryUrl).then(function() {
          console.log(gapi.client);
          var res = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate({
          spreadsheetId: '1_dAJ8QqxFjKD1Z32vKe_ERh6AFYlALn0gtGIIifowC8',
          requests: requests
            });
          res.then(function(data) {
          console.log(data)
       });
     }); 


    //writeSheet(); 




}
```

manifest.js

```
{
  "name": "Daca",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Update spreadsheet on user Submit",
  "browser_action": {


  },
  "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js","jquery.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "<my url>", "https://apis.google.com/js/client.js", "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", "identity", "https://content-sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/*"],

  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<my url>"],
    "js": ["contentscript.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }
    ],
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "139751156265-mvroahocc1d4g7e848q44f1uqk0e78mc.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [

        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
    ]
    },
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'"

}
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, did you find a solution?